# Skipping locked section already in use

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a critical section which is to be executed only once but is invoked by many scenarios. How can I execute this thread proc and skip all the rest of the calls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Assuming this uses calls from multiple threads, I used volatile.
volatile bool executed = false;
object lockExcecuted = new object();

void DoSomething()
{
    lock (lockExecuted)
    {
        if (executed) return;
        executed = true;
    }
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If executed is only ever within the lock block, you don't need volatile on executed.  There is a memory barrier at the start and end of the lock block making any read/writes visible to other threads

Comment: Interlocked.Exchange oddly doesn't support `bool`.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to use int instead of bool for Interlocked.Exchange.

Comment: @Peter: Can you point me to a reference for that statement on not needing volatile?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx is one; ECMA 335 sections 12.6.5 and 12.6.7 details Monitor.Enter/Exit and their acquire/release semantics implications.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool hasExecuted = false;

static readonly object lockObject = new object();

static void Method()
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        if(!hasExecuted)
        {
            // run code
            hasExecuted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lock is the preferred method; unless you have more detailed requirements.

EDIT: the addition of "only once" means lock is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lock` to allow only one thread to access the critical section and when it's complete set a flag saying it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on ur scenario. If this section returns a value, u can use the new feature of .Net 4.0 - [Lazy(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808725.aspx)

Of course, you can always just set a flag within ur critical section, and check its value before executing (which is sometimes being done when using the singleton pattern)